# asp.net submit process

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a form with 2 labels initializing random numbers and a text box to check if the answer is correct after adding the two random numbers. The problem i am having is SUBMIT processes the next set of random numbers and so the result is always incorrect. here is the code i have so far.

```
namespace _2ndGradeMath
{

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblNum1.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
            lblNum3.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
            int num1 = int.Parse(lblNum1.Text);
            int num2 = int.Parse(lblNum3.Text);
            lblAnswer.Text = (num1 + num2).ToString();
            lblAnswer.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text != lblAnswer.Text)
            {
                Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:alert('Incorrect');");
            }

            else if (TextBox1.Text == lblAnswer.Text)
            {
                Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:alert('Correct');");
            }

            TextBox1.Text = "";           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need to do if the answer is correct? Could you use a customvalidator?

Comment: On every postback, the full page lifecycle is processed and `Page_Load` is one of its steps. To avoid changing the value everytime, wrap that code inside your `Page_Load` with a `if(!this.IsPostBack){...}` block.

Comment: after the page is processed i have an alert message showing if the answer is correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)** to only run the initializing code when the page is initially loaded:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)    
   {
        lblNum1.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
        lblNum3.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
        int num1 = int.Parse(lblNum1.Text);
        int num2 = int.Parse(lblNum3.Text);
        lblAnswer.Text = (num1 + num2).ToString();
        lblAnswer.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 - this is the more appropriate answer ***if*** new numbers aren't supposed to be generated on every post back.

Comment: i tried this before, but this doesnt allow generating new numbers.

Comment: It all depends on *when* you want the new numbers to be generated... You can always call Random again whenever you want. But if you *regenerate* them before checking the previous values like you do now - you'll never get a correct answer

Comment: This is it. Was able to load new numbers on page load and the evaluation is correct. Also had a problem with the javascript alert. It seems it was evaluating those lines of code in the order the occur each time the page loaded. All odd were correct and all even were wrong regardless of the response. Thank you very much for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding this code to `PreRender`:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Answer"] = lblAnswer.Text;
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

and then in the `Click` grab the answer from `Session` like this:

```
if (TextBox1.Text != Session["Answer"])
```

and bear in mind **I'm assuming** that you actually *want* to generate new numbers on **every** post back with this answer.

Comment: Right! I would like the page to generate new numbers as it is in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @chikskaso, then this should work for you. Before rendering the page you grab the new answer, and in between load and render you leverage the value from the previous post back.

Comment: Alright! Thanks very much Michael. I am trying to work it out the way you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. You are loading *new* random numbers each time the page loads. That's what the Page_Load function does: it runs each time the page loads which includes every time the page is submitted. So when a user presses submit new random numbers are assigned, which makes his answer wrong. You need to assign random numbers in only two instances:

First, when the page loads for the first time. Which can be done by checking the property IsPostBackis false.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(!IsPostBack){
            lblNum1.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
            lblNum3.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
      }
.
.
.
}
```

Second, when the user answers correctly.

```
else if (TextBox1.Text == lblAnswer.Text)
{
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:alert('Correct');");
        lblNum1.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
        lblNum3.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
}
```

Comment: I was doing a few other things wrong. Shouldnt have used that onclick javascript alert. Turns out it only gave an alert according to line of code being executed, so even if a response was wrong, but the line being executed showed "correct" that is just what it went with, the same for incorrect responses. I went with a label this time and it works just fine. Thank you very much for your help.